# How to get day of the week based on date in another field in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

## Issue

I have two text field in a model-form.
First is text field showing date and second is a normal text field.
I'm using jquery datepicker for dates
Please see my code blow

## Code

Html:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="start_day" value="<?php echo $start_day; ?>" class="start_day" tabindex="0" />
<input type="text" name="dlvry_day" value="<?php echo $dlvry_day; ?>" class="dlvry_day" >
```

JavaScript:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".start_day").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true
});

});
```

I need to make the second textbox as non typeable and need to automatically display the day of the date, when user selects from first textbox(i.e the one showing the date).

Note: I am saving these two field values using php.

A quick solution is much helpful.

Comment: Got your Point @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0):

That's how you make it read only.

```
 $("#datepicker").readonlyDatepicker(true);
```

This is how to set today's date to datepicker field

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But my question is to display only "day" of the date, when selecting date from first field and to display it on second field.

Comment: you want to see the day on the second field only?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone who give their best to solve my issue.
Anyway , i found a way to get my desired output.
Please check the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".dlvry_day").attr('disabled','disabled');
jQuery(".start_day").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true, 
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var Sel = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
        Sel = Sel.toDateString();
        Sel = Sel.split(' ');
        var days = new Array();
        days['Sun'] = "Sunday";
        days['Mon'] ="Monday";
        days['Tue'] = "Tuesday";
        days['Wed'] = "Wednesday";
        days['Thu'] = "Thursday";
        days['Fri'] = "Friday";
        days['Sat'] = "Saturday";
      var days = days[Sel[0]];
      jQuery(".dlvry_day").val(days);
      }
});

});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".start_day").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
    // When datepicker date is changed
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        // This is selected date of .start_day
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        // Update .dlvry_day date to our selected date
        $(".dlvry_day").datepicker("update", minDate.getDate());
        // Can be used like that 
        //$('.dlvry_day').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate.getDate());
        // Making disabled the .dlvry_day
        $('.dlvry_day').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: NOPE. Comments in code are OK, but you should add a description. Nine times out of ten those coming here will not read the comments.

Comment: Okey i'll do next time :)

Comment: NOPE. Not next time. *Every* time.